# Capturar precios de 2000 url distintas de patron desestructurado html web scraping

Tags: scraping, nlp, web-scrapping, scrap

El problema es extraer del producto principal el precio en alrededor 2000 url de distintos sitios web y el patrón de html en general no existe para lo que necesito, en las imágenes compartidas se ve cada precio no está armado con el típico "", esto corresponde a casi un 60% de las url, así que cualquier captura la debo considerar como de una fuente html desestructurada.

El código compartido usé una técnica básica de capturar un texto de forma mimificada de todo un body con filtros y por último una regexp que me dió un consistencia del 5%, es poco útil mi trabajo.

Quiero saber si es usar el aprendizaje automático con entrenar un modelo utilizando técnicas como el procesamiento del lenguaje natural (NLP) y la visión artificial para extraer precios de las nuevas páginas HTML es la única alternativa que necesito en esto. Es algo nuevo para mí y dificil de lograr.

Muchas gracias de antemano por cualquier aporte. Saludos!

```
const { convertJsonToCsv } = require('../convert/jsonToCsv.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const scraphtml = (url, title) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                // Cargar solo el string HTML del body en Cheerio
                const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

                // Obtener el contenido del body
                const bodyContent = $('body').html();

                // Crear una nueva instancia de Cheerio con el contenido del body
                const $body = cheerio.load(bodyContent);

                // Eliminar todas las etiquetas y su contenido sin texto relevante
                $body('script, noscript, style, form').remove();

                // Crear una matriz para contener todos los atributos
                const attributes = [];

                // Iterar sobre cada etiqueta HTML y obtener sus atributos
                $body('*').each(function () {
                    const tagAttributes = Object.keys($body(this).attr()).filter(attr => !attributes.includes(attr));
                    attributes.push(...tagAttributes);
                });

                // Seleccionar todas las etiquetas HTML y eliminar sus atributos
                $body('*').removeAttr(...attributes);

                // Texto resultante de Cheerio
                const text = $body.text().toLowerCase();

                // Reducimos el texto eliminando espacios y saltos de líneas
                shorthtml = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
                // console.log("texto corto >>>>>>>>>>>>> " + shorthtml);

                // Adaptamos el "title" reemplazando los espacios por "\s" porque JavaScript no admite aserciones de búsqueda posterior con patrones de longitud variable.
                const titleBlock = title.replace(/\s/g, "\\s");

                // Logramos patrón de captura solo número de precio protagonista.
                const pattern = new RegExp(`\\b(${titleBlock}\\s.*?)\\$(\\d{1,3}(?:[,.]?\\d{3})*(?:[,.]\\d{2})?)`, "g");// 11

                let match;
                let numberPart;
                while ((match = pattern.exec(shorthtml)) !== null) {
                    numberPart = match[2].replace(',', '.');
                    console.log("resutado capturado del match >>>>>>" + match[0] + "<<<<<");
                    break;
                };
                resolve(numberPart);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};

const scrapingPriceWeb = async (inDbJson, outPathJson, outPathCsv) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(inDbJson) || fs.statSync(inDbJson).size === 0) {
            return reject(new Error(`Input file '${inDbJson}' does not exist or is empty`));
        }
        fs.readFile(inDbJson, async (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            // Convertir los datos a un objeto JavaScript
            const datos = JSON.parse(data);

            for (let i = 0; i < datos.table.rows.length; i++) {
                const product = datos.table.rows[i];
                const title = (product.c[2].v).toLowerCase();
                const url = product.c[3].v;
                const numIdList = product.c[0].v;
                let precioPosta = product.c[6];
                console.log("-----------------------------------------");
                console.log(`Id>>> ${numIdList} Titulo>>> ${title}`);
                let resultado = { v: 0, f: 0 };

                try {
                    const datahtml = await scraphtml(url, title);
                    resultado = { v: datahtml, f: datahtml };
                    precioPosta = resultado;
                    console.log("Precio extraído : " + datahtml);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
                datahtml===undefined?
                datos.table.rows[i].c[6] = "SIN RESULTADO":
                datos.table.rows[i].c[6] = precioPosta;                
            };

            fs.writeFile(outPathJson, JSON.stringify(datos), (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
                console.log('scraper.js agregó los "precio posta" en output.json');
            });

            // Creamos un file csv con "datos"
            const fileCsv = convertJsonToCsv(datos)

            fs.writeFile(outPathCsv, fileCsv, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
                console.log('Creado archivo "outputPricesScrapWeb.csv" con los precios reales de la Web');
            });
        });
    });
};

module.exports = { scrapingPriceWeb };
```

[image: Ejemplo 1]

[image: Ejemplo 2]

[image: Ejemplo 3]